# Update item inside a mongodb object

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I'm trying to `save()` a record inside an object. Problem is I just get `MongoCursor()-errors` or `unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY)`. For an instance:

This is my MongoDB-collection:

```
[
  {
    "id": "dfK15ale12",
    "keys": {
      "gcm_key": "abc",
      "app_secret": "123"
    }
  }
```

]

I want to update the `gcm_key` inside `keys`, this is my PHP code:

```
$db->apps->save(
    array("_id" => $update['_id'])
    array("$push" => 'keys.gcm_android' => $gcm_android);
);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY) in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\update.php on line 3
```

I have googled and looked here on Stack to find answers, and I've found nothing. Maybe I've missed something. I don't know, what is the correct mongoDB cursor and which is the easiest way to `save()` the `gcm_key`?

Comment: `array("$push" => array('keys.gcm_android' => $gcm_android))` with the added array(

Comment: Your also missing a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you seem to want is [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

```
$db->apps->update(
    array('_id' => $update['_id']),
    array('$push' => array('keys.gcm_android' => $gcm_android))
);
```

But is un-clear what you want your end result to be. This would produce the following:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532aa3d15fcd8ecb9ae23567"),
    "id" : "dfK15ale12",
    "keys" : {
            "gcm_key" : "abc",
            "app_secret" : "123",
            "gcm_android" : [
                    123
            ]
    }
}
```

Assuming that you had value `123` in your `$gcm_android` variable. If you have an array then look at [$pushAll](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/).

If you are just looking to add another property to keys then use [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

```
$db->apps->update(
    array('_id' => $update['_id']),
    array('set' => array('keys.gcm_android' => $gcm_android))
);
```

Where this is your result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532aa3d15fcd8ecb9ae23567"),
    "id" : "dfK15ale12",
    "keys" : {
            "gcm_key" : "abc",
            "app_secret" : "123",
            "gcm_android" : 123
    }
}
```

Comment: I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY)"

Comment: @Jack typos are fixed

Comment: Beware of string interpolation, "$set" and "$push" should be surrounded by single quotes...

Comment: @LaFabriqueDeCode That's what I get for cut and paste :<. I think there is enough information on the page to solve the issue now

Comment: I got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'`, seems odd.

Comment: @Jack You ssem to doing cut and paste without looking as well. Points: 1. "save" was the wrong function, you need update, that is what I was answering. 2. Not sure what you want to do by your question, there are options, also in the answer. 3. You had syntax errors in your code, also copied here but now fixed. So please check again and realize these mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong:

```
$db->apps->save(
    array("_id" => $update['_id'])
    array("$push" => 'keys.gcm_android' => $gcm_android);
);
```

Should be:

```
$db->apps->update(
    array("_id" => $update['_id']),
    array('$push' => array('keys.gcm_android' => $gcm_android))
);
```

That is what the error is telling you right here:

> unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY)

It is actually speaking first of the comma and then of the array

Comment: `.save()` does not take two arguments so is basically the wrong function to use

Comment: I get "Undefined variable: push"

Comment: I got "null" as echo json `echo json_encode($update);`

Comment: @Jack If $update is null then you need to find out why it is not being assigned correctly. I would strongly recommend you look at the PHP documentation more and at the MongoDB driver documentation as well a bit more. It is starting to get that we are about to code this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db->apps->update(
    array('_id' => new MongoId('YOURIDGOESHERE')),
    array('$set' => array('keys.gcm_android' => $gcm_android))
);
```